# How to compute inner product between two networks'parameters

Tags: neural-network, data-product

Consider a neural network with $f(x) = w^T_2 \sigma(w^T_1 x) $ where $\sigma(.)$ is a activation function such as ReLU. $w_2 \in R^{d \times k}, w_1 \in R^{k \times o}$ are two matrices. I would like to compute the inner product between two initialization of model's parameters $\theta =(w_2, w_1)$ and $\theta'=(w'_2, w'_1)$.
Should we stack all elements of networks parameter into a single vector, i.e $\theta, \theta'$ will be a big vector with the number of entries equal to $w\times k + k \times o$. Then we just compute the inner product between two vectors. Is that a good way to compute the inner product between two model' parameters to measure how similarity they are ?

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the [Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm) between the two matrices. Also look up this related article on [distance measures between matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507742/distance-similarity-between-two-matrices)/